# ClipBorad's Clip text is not comming directly after putting it in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-sharedpreferences, android-jsinterface

Here I am trying to get clipboard text I have tried both ways first i tried with clipboard and second with sharedpreferences in both the cases behaviour is same when i select the word from my custom webview and copy that word using jsinterface i got the word sucessfully but when immideatly aftre that i try to get that world it give me anoter world suppos first i copy word "A" then I copy word "B" and then immideatly try to get "B" It gives me "A" here is my code inside webviews Action Item clicked

```
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_done:
            getSelectedData();
            mode.finish();
            return true;
            break;
        }
   }
```

and my getSelectedData() function

```
private void getSelectedData() {

    String js = "(function getSelectedText() {" + "var txt;"
            + "if (window.getSelection) {"
            + "txt = window.getSelection().toString();"
            + "} else if (window.document.getSelection) {"
            + "txt = window.document.getSelection().toString();"
            + "} else if (window.document.selection) {"
            + "txt = window.document.selection.createRange().text;" + "}"
            + "JSInterface.getText(txt);" + "})()";
    // calling the js function
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        evaluateJavascript("javascript:" + js, null);
    } else {
        loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
    }
    showDialog();
}
```

in this function getText is function from javascriptInterface and my              webappInterface class is as under

```
    public class WebAppInterface {
           Context mContext;

       WebAppInterface(Context c) {
       mContext = c;
    }

@JavascriptInterface
public void getText(String text) {
    // put selected text into clipdata
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text",text);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    sp.edit().putString("COPIED_TEXT",text).commit();
}
}
```

and In my showDialog function I am trying to get text which is put in sharedpreferences and clipboard text but it get previously saved text as i described above how to resolve this issue ihave tried both way in showDIalog Function like this but no proper working found

```
     //ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        //String selectedClipboardText = "";
        //selectedClipboardText = (String) clipboard
        //      .getText();
        String selectedClipboardText = "";
        selectedClipboardText=BilingualNews.BNPref.getString("COPIED_TEXT", "");

        selectedClipboardText = getFilteredSelfTextWord(selectedClipboardText);
```